# Problem connecting two DC-DC converters in one circuit

Tags: power-supply, dc, dc-dc-converter, converter, isolation

I'm building an audio mixer for microphones, and have a problem with the power supply part.

I'm designing this board to work with several voltages which are +/-15V, 5V, and 48V (for phantom power).

I used two DC-DC converters.  One is the 15V to 5V for which I just followed the circuit give in the XLSEMI XL2001E1 chip datasheet.

I have the schematic in the figure below.

[image]

The other DC-DC converter is 5V to 48V phantom power. I followed the circuit from a web site that made it for a phantom power supply.

My schematic looks like in the figure below.

[image]

As you can see from these two pictures, the two DC-DC converters are connected to each other, which should be fine in my mind.

When I built this design on a PCB, the thing didn't work as intended.

As the 15V power turned on the board didn't turn on. I did some troubleshooting and found that each circuit worked if it was isolated, but they cannot work together.

I'm still trying to figure out what the problem is.

- Is the load too much for the first converter?
- Does it create an inrush current that makes the chip shut down?

Can anyone give any suggestions or help on how to connect these two circuit? Adjusting the capacitor/inductor maybe? Is there a way to make it work or is it better to supply a separate power supply 5V for the second converter?

Comment: Why not power MC34063 from 15V? That would avoid losses from double conversion...

Comment: Yeah, i also would place in parallel and not in series. And you might be correct about the load being to much for the first regulator.

Comment: @bobflux The reason the second converter didn't use 15V is that I try not to change from the reference circuit, from the website https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/5v-48v-dc-converter-phantom-power-supplies

Comment: There is a full design procedure in the TI data sheet with a very similar project  (12V > 28V) so reworking the maths in the step-by-step instructions for 15V > 40V should be easy.

Comment: I would add a note that even once you get it working I would expect this sort of thing to disappoint in that application. While it is possible to do a switched mode supply for a mic amp and have it be good, it takes some work and experience to pull it off. For a beginner I would strongly advise that an old school linear supply with a line frequency transformer is MUCH more likely to be satisfactory.